# how can i loop through a json array requested from an api?

Tags: php, json, api, instagram

im requesting information from the instagram api in php like this:

```
<?php $relation = $instagram->get('users/'.$item->id.'/relationship'); 
..
```

which return this json data array for me:

```
object(stdClass)#58(2){
    [
        "meta"
    ]=>object(stdClass)#59(1){
        [
            "code"
        ]=>int(200)
    }[
        "data"
    ]=>object(stdClass)#60(3){
        [
            "outgoing_status"
        ]=>string(7)"follows"[
            "target_user_is_private"
        ]=>bool(true)[
            "incoming_status"
        ]=>string(4)"none"
    }
}
```

note: i used var_dump($relation) to bring this out

what I'm trying to do is loop through this array and display the outgoing status and the incoming status i.e

```
loop(json-array){
echo outgoing_status;
echo incoming_status;
}
```

thank you very much..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an object (instance of `stdClass`, the generic object), not an array.

```
$outgoing_status = $response->data->outgoing_status;
$incoming_status = $response->data->incoming_status;
```

As a side note, use `json_decode($json, TRUE)` to return the data as an associative array instead of an object.

Comment: oh thanks, but how do i loop this object, and is $response = $relation

Comment: thanks it works +1, can i ask once more thing is it better to have it as json or object?

Comment: @MidnightCoder You mean **array** or an object. It is up to you.